# How to find the number of friend-of-friend (shortest path of two edges) to a user?

Tags: algorithm, network-programming, shortest-path

Suppose a graph G = (V,E) is given where V is a set of users and edge (v,w) in E if users v and w are friends.

Then, how do I write an algorithm to find the number of friend-of-friend connections to a user? what about its big-O estimate?

I think I can use how many v's have shortest path of two edges to the user, but I don't know exactly how to approach.

Comment: Can you use standard bfs traversal ( along with maintaining distance from source node ) to find all the nodes which are two distance apart from the user.

Comment: @Vishal That will be inefficient.

Comment: OK. It was not clear to me from the question if this is expected to be done for each user in the graph or only for a single user. My answer as assuming need to be done for single user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a set of vertices adjacent to the first.  (For example use a hash to make lookups `O(1)`.  For each vertex adjacent to the second, check whether it is adjacent to the first.

This will take space `O(E1)` and time `O(E1 + E2)` where `E1` and `E2` are the number of edges for each vertex.

A naive breadth-first search will be slower because for each vertex found from `E1` you need to look at all of its edges in turn.  If we average `n` edges per vertex, this would be expected to be `O(n^2)`.  But in practice it is worse than that.  Most people aren't superconnected, but know someone who is.  And those superconnected people can add a lot of edges, quickly.